# impossible to generate bundle

Tags: symfony, bundle

i'm new to the symfony framework and i'm trying to generate my first bundle ,
i use this command `php bin/console generate:bundle` but it's not working.

The error message :

`There are no commands defined in the "generate" namespace`.

You may be looking for a command provided by the `SensioGeneratorBundle` which is currently not installed.

Try running `composer require sensio/generator-bundle`.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/gKdsD.jpg

I've tried to install composer repositories with the command `composer require sensio/generator-bundle` and nothing has changed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We're not making bundle in Symfony 4.

While it was "good practice" withg Symfony 2, since the new skeleton, it's not the case anymore.

Your default bundle is now `App`, all your code goes in `src/`, and all your view (twig files) goes in `template/`

Answer (score 1):

In symfony 4, this bundle is deprecated, you must use the maker-bundle, unfortunately there is no bundle generator available. So you'll need to code your bundle from scratch with the official documentation: https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/best_practices.html

By the way, bundle are deprecated and are now only use to share packaged code between projects.

More informations at: https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles.html

Comment: https://medium.com/@miguel.alcaino/create-a-symfony-4-shareable-reusable-bundle-and-take-advantage-of-makerbundle-or-any-symfony-98e6251bfaef